# using predict.glmboost function with model trained by caret and glmboost

Tags: r, r-caret, predict

I've started to using `R caret` package to train/predict machine learning models. I've decided to write this post because I don't know how to read the documentation and I didn't find any web where it is explained. My case is the next:

I'm trying to predict data tags through the following fitted/trained model:

```
glmModel <- train(Survived ~ ., data=training, 
           method='glmboost', 
           metric="Accuracy", 
           maximize=TRUE,
           tuneLength=2,
           preProc=c("center", "scale", "YeoJohnson"), 
           trControl = control)
```

I want to predict the new data tags with the `predict` function but the documentation show this:

```
Usage

predict (object, ...)


Arguments

object     a model object for which prediction is desired.
...        additional arguments affecting the predictions produced.
```

I was reading documentation and tested the model as follows:

```
glmModel.class <- predict(glmModel, newdata=test, type=c("raw"))

glmModel.probs <- predict(glmModel, newdata=test, type=c("prob"))
```

That runs ok, but I have seen in a web that the `predict` function allows more than these parameters. As `predict` is a generic function, I've used the `methods('predict')` command to show the different prediction functions which are encompassed into `predict` generic function. One of these options is `predict.glmboost`, but when I try to use the generic `predict` function with the `predict.glmboost` parameters `R` returns an error indicating that parameters doesn't exist.

My problem is that I don't know how to follow the `R` documentation to apply a generic `predict` function adapating it to a specific model that was previously trained with `train` function.

Comment: You can check the class of the object using `class`.

Comment: you are looking for `caret::predict.train` which is called by default on `train` objects. So `predict(glmModel, ....)` works just fine. When you call `predict.glmboost` it fails since that functions is for models of class `glmboost`.